# Change the background to an image

Tags: c#, image, background, windows-store-apps

I am trying to change the background of my windows store app. This is the code I am using, it does not throw an error but for some reason it does not work. Anybody knows how to change the background of my main page?

```
string path = "ms-appx:///Assets/rainySky.png";

ImageBrush image = new ImageBrush();
image.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(path));

Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
rootFrame.Background = image;
```

Comment: where do you run the code? Are you sure the `path` points to some valid image?

Comment: I wrote a function called changeBackground and I call it when I press a button on the mainpage. I know that the image is in my assets folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the background image when the application is launched you can use the following code in the OnLaunched event:

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

    // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
    // just ensure that the window is active
    if (rootFrame == null)
    {
        // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
        rootFrame = new Frame();

        rootFrame.Background = new ImageBrush
        {
            Stretch = Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Stretch.UniformToFill,
            ImageSource = new BitmapImage { UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Image.jpg") }
        };

        if (args.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
        {
            //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
        }

        // Place the frame in the current Window
        Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
    }

    if (rootFrame.Content == null)
    {
        // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
        // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
        // parameter
        if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), args.Arguments))
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
        }
    }
    // Ensure the current window is active
    Window.Current.Activate();
}
```

Comment: What if I want to change it after I launch it?

Answer (score 0):

```
this.RootFrame.Background= new ImageBrush
{
    ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/rainySky.png", UriKind.Relative))
};
```